# Does anyone know how to use the IDragDropManagerInterop interface with a desktop application?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, windows-runtime, interop

I'm trying to use WinRT APIs with my Rust desktop application (since WinRT is simpler when you get it working, and it doesn't require unsafe code), but I can't seem to figure out how the use [`IDragDropManagerInterop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dragdropinterop/nn-dragdropinterop-idragdropmanagerinterop).

I think I somehow need to get the drag/drop manager interface from some Windows API (I thought it was [`RoGetActivationFactory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/roapi/nf-roapi-rogetactivationfactory), but I'm pretty sure that's wrong). Then from there, I can use `IDragDropManagerInterop` to get the drag/drop manager for my application window, and I can go from there.

I've been trying to figure this out, and I think the answer might be on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/WinRT/interfaces, but I just have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: The `*Interop` interfaces are commonly provided to close the gap between (some flavor of) a `CoreApplication` and a classic desktop application. The standard pattern is to ask the `CoreApplication` for its implementation (`CoreDragDropManager.GetForCurrentView()`) and then query the returned interface for the `*Interop` interface using `QueryInterface` (or [`cast`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/trait.ComInterface.html#method.cast) in Rust). The official documentation is insufficient to use those interfaces.

Comment: Yeah I am still fairly new to winrt and still not an expert on win32 so I'm not really sure what you mean. Can you just break it down for me please?

Comment: If you are writing a classic desktop application (one that registers a window class, creates one or more windows, and explicitly dispatches messages), `IDragDropManagerInterop` is of no use. It is useful only if you use a `CoreApplication`-based application model, *and* wish to extend it with UI based on native `HWND`s. What application model are you using, a classic desktop application or a `CoreApplication`-based one?

Comment: I'm using a classic desktop application. I'm creating a tauri app using rust which uses tao under the hood for windowing (so most of the internals are abstracted away from me). Although I know that tao is just a fork of winit, and from this: https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/issues/1564, it looks like winit still just uses a desktop application approach instead of using the newer CoreApplication setup. Basically all I can get from tauri is the raw HWND of the window, and I was hoping that with that I would be able to set up a drag and drop event system.

Comment: Correct, the `winit` crate follows the classic desktop application model. You can still implement drag-and-drop functionality. [`RegisterDragDrop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-registerdragdrop) registers a window as the target of arbitrary OLE objects. If you only want to accept files [`DragAcceptFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragacceptfiles) provides a simpler interface for this specific purpose.

Comment: As I said in my original post, I was only using winrt apis because they seemed memory safe and easier (once I get them working). But it's starting to look like it's not really possible, maybe it will be if winit changes to an CoreApplication approach, who knows. Still, I think I'll just do it the old fashioned way as you said.